# Does Angular 2 have re-rendering optimization?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have been using React from couple of months and React doesn't simply re-rendering a component completely instead it finds the difference and makes those changes. Does Angular 2 does something like this?

And also whenever a change in state is detected does Angular 2 re-render all the components from the root node or does it only re-render those specific components and their sub-tree whose change is detected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> React doesn't simply re-rendering a component completely instead it finds the difference and makes those changes. Does Angular 2 does something like this?

Conceptually yes, it does not re-render entire components.

Angular builds a change detector object for each component/directive.  Template bindings (which includes input property bindings) are tracked inside these change detector objects.  When change detection runs, by default, each binding is dirty checked for changes.  If a change is found, the changed value is propagated to the child component (if an input property changed) or to the DOM.  That's it.  The entire template/view is not re-rendered.  Only the changed values are updated in the DOM.  When Angular change detection finishes, the browser notices the DOM changes and updates what we see on the screen.

> whenever a change in state is detected does Angular 2 re-render all the components from the root node or does it only re-render those specific components and their sub-tree whose change is detected?

Angular doesn't detect changes to some model/data objects.  Rather, it only detects changes to template bindings.

By default, each time change detection runs, it starts from the root component and checks all components for changes, in depth-first order, using those change detector objects.  As described above, only template bindings with changes are updated.  So, I wouldn't say that Angular ever re-renders a component... it only modifies those parts of the DOM where a template binding changed.

You can configure a component to use the `OnPush` change detection strategy to limit when that component and its descendants are checked for changes.  You can also completely [detach()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) a component from the change detector tree, which means that component and its descendants will not be change detected until you reattach().

Answer (score 2):

Angular is not using virtual DOM as React do. No need for that in context of Angular.

If you have `<input>` and need to set its value in runtime to something else you don't need to change all DOM around it. You just call setValue() on that element and that's it.

The same applies to any other DOM element. For example if you have this:

```
<div>{{someVar}}</div>
```

and Angular detects that someVar was changed it will change content of only that particular `<div>`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok `setValue()` here is any function that sets value of input element. Like in jQuery `$.val(...)` or DOM property assignment: `input.value = "..."`.

Answer (score 1):

Angular only renders where it detects changes.

AFAIK there is some room for improvments in `*ngFor` where it sometimes re-renders too many items when some are added/removed in the middle or the beginning but that is a known issue and will be fixed eventually.

From my comment below

> In fact Angular doesn't need re-rendering optimization because it only does anything when bound values change and then it only changes the DOM where it is bound to the changed value. Angular doesn't have a virtual DOM that it needs to mirror to the actual DOM.

Comment: Does it re-render everything from root component or only those components whose state has changed?

Comment: What means "re-renders" in context of "added/removed"? _When the item is added, it renders it first time, when "removed", then the item is just removed._

Comment: We cannot go with english meaning of words? I want to know what Angular 2 does? Does it re-render everything from root component or only those components whose state has changed?

Comment: @NarayanPrusty Angular updates bindings `{{someValue}}`. It doesn't re-render everything from root except once on the initial load.

Comment: @tenbits There is a but in `*ngFor` where it removes and re-adds too many items when the array `*ngFor` is bound to is modified - instead of just removing and inserting the actually removed/inserted items.

Comment: I still have still confusion. Does it updates bindings of all the components from root node or only bindings of those components whose state has changed?

Comment: No, it doesn't. In fact Angular doesn't need re-rendering optimization because it only does anything when bound values change and then it only changes the DOM where it is bound to the changed value. Angular doesn't have a virtual DOM that it needs to mirror to the actual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 is using [zone.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone) for **onChange** rendering. Usually when a change is detected, it will trigger **changeDetection** that component and all the children, but you also can have control to change that, to force render some things or not render when you don't like angular2 behavior.

Here is a very good talk about how [Angular2 change detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxD91DWkGM) works : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxD91DWkGM

LE: Just to clarify, it will not re-render the component and all the children, it will detect and trigger changes for all of those, but will render only what is necessary.

Comment: "when a change is detected, it will trigger changeDetection" -- I don't understand what that means.  Change detection has to already be running/triggered, and then changes are detected.  Maybe you meant to say "when a (zone.js monkey-patched) event fires, it will trigger change detection"?